# not using setter property on some control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created `<Style TargetType="Label">` I am using it on all labels.

But there is one label that I don't want to use this Style there I just want to stay default .

Any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Label Style="{x:Null}"  />
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Just create a named style for the one you don't want to have the implicit style, and assign it to it.

for example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="MyWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="DefaultStyle" TargetType="Label"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainCanvas">
        <Label>Sample 1</Label>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}">Sample 2</Label>
        <Label>Sample 3</Label>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

in this example all labels will have red foreground except the ones you assign the DefaultStyle will have a default style (foreground black)

Comment: Cannot find resource named '{DefaultStyle}'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Comment: you have to define it in the resource:
<Style x:Key="DefaultStyle" TargetType="Label"/>

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is something like a `DoNotApplyStyle` Boolean on a `UIElement`. What you can do is simply give that special label it's own unique style which mimics the default style.

```
<Label Text="Special label">
  <Label.Style>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
      ...
    </Style>
  </Label.Style>
</Label>
```